# return one string from colums data

Tags: postgresql

I've result set from query `select * from personal."phoneNumbers"` like this
prefix

```
pref |number
-----|--------
"12 "|"4589524"
"077"|"7090701"
"050"|"2561024"
```

But I want to return data like

```
(12) 4589524;(077) 7090701; (050) 2561024
```

How to do this with postgresql ?

Comment: Use string concatenation (`||`) and `string_agg`. See linked question.

Comment: @CraigRinger A tad questionable to mark this as a duplicate, at least of the question indicated. The above problem requires trimming and concatenation *prior* to `string_agg`, making it far less straightforward than in the answer provided.

Comment: `SELECT string_agg('(' || btrim(pref) || ') ' || number, '; ') AS pref_number FROM personal."phoneNumbers"`

Comment: @Patrick Didn't notice the need for trimming too, fair point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the string operators and functions to construct a single phone number in the format that you want:

```
'(' || btrim(pref) || ') ' || number
```

This, obviously, yields a string for each record that you process. You can then use the aggregation function `string_agg()` to string (no pun intended) the extended phone numbers from all the records together into one, with the appropriate separator between phone numbers:

```
SELECT string_agg('(' || btrim(pref) || ') ' || number, '; ') AS pref_number
FROM personal."phoneNumbers"
```